# Error using helm function in argocd-notifications template

Tags: kubernetes-helm, argocd

I'm trying to fetch a specific parameter from my values file to send to slack when a deployment is complete.

However, `(call .repo.GetAppDetails).Helm.GetParameterValueByName "image.tag"` always throws an error that doesn't seem to make any sense.

Argocd version:

```
argocd: v2.7.6+00c914a
BuildDate: 2023-06-20T21:18:20Z
GitCommit: 00c914a948d9e8ad99be8bd82a368fbdeba12f88
GitTreeState: clean
GoVersion: go1.19.10
Compiler: gc
Platform: linux/amd64
```

Error:

```
time="2023-09-11T18:34:23Z" level=error msg="Failed to notify recipient {slack argo-cd} defined in resource argocd/dev-neo: template: app-sync-succeeded:2:37: executing \"app-sync-succeeded\" at <(call .repo.GetAppDetails).Helm.GetParameterValueByName>: error calling GetParameterValueByName: value method github.com/argoproj/argo-cd/v2/util/notification/expression/shared.CustomHelmAppSpec.GetParameterValueByName called using nil *CustomHelmAppSpec pointer" resource=argocd/dev-myproject
```

Template:

```yaml
template.app-sync-succeeded: |
    email:
      subject: Application {{.app.metadata.name}} has been successfully synced.
    message: |
      {{if eq .serviceType "slack"}}:white_check_mark:{{end}} Application {{.app.metadata.name}} has been successfully synced at {{.app.status.operationState.finishedAt}}.
      Author: {{(call .repo.GetCommitMetadata .app.status.sync.revision).Author}}
      Sync operation details are available at: {{.context.argocdUrl}}/applications/{{.app.metadata.name}}?operation=true .
    slack:
      attachments: |
        [{
          "title": "{{ .app.metadata.name}}",
          "title_link":"{{.context.argocdUrl}}/applications/{{.app.metadata.name}}",
          "color": "#18be52",
          "fields": [
          {
            "title": "Sync Status",
            "value": "{{.app.status.sync.status}}",
            "short": true
          },
          {
            "title": "Tag",
            "value": "{{ (call .repo.GetAppDetails).Helm.GetParameterValueByName "image.tag" }}",
            "short": true
          },
          {
            "title": "Repository",
            "value": "{{.app.spec.source.repoURL}}",
            "short": true
          }
          {{range $index, $c := .app.status.conditions}}
          {{if not $index}},{{end}}
          {{if $index}},{{end}}
          {
            "title": "{{$c.type}}",
            "value": "{{$c.message}}",
            "short": true
          }
          {{end}}
          ]
        }]
      deliveryPolicy: Post
      groupingKey: ""
      notifyBroadcast: false
```